# Spring AOP - expression "&&" Not working while combining pointcuts

Tags: spring, spring-aop

**Aspect Class:**

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("e1() && e2()")
    public void loggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("before execution of the method");
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public String com.spring.Employee.getName())")
    public void e1(){}

    @Pointcut("execution(public String com.spring.Department.getName())")
    public void e2(){}

}
```

**Client Class:**

public class AspectClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    Employee emp = (Employee) context.getBean("employee");
    System.out.println(emp.getEmpId());
    System.out.println(emp.getName());
    System.out.println(emp.getDepartment().getName());

}

**Config file:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<bean id= "employee" class="com.spring.Employee" autowire="byName">
<property name="empId" value="7329" />
<property name="name" value="Sagar" />
</bean>

<bean id= "department" class="com.spring.Department" >
<property name="name" value="ApplicationManagement" />
<property name="typeOfProjects" value="Maintenance" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.spring.LoggingAspect"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

**Explanation:**

@Before("e1() && e2()")
When I just call either e1() or e2() individually, it works but not both at same time.
I dont get any errors., Just the advices are not called.
I am using spring 3.2.3
AspectJ and AOP alliance jar files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which is as expected. The pointcut never matches it will never match both the execution e1 and execution e2 on the same time. Instead of `&&` you probably want `||` .

It basically is an if statement and both sides have to resolve to `true` a

Comment: Hi Deinum,
Thanks for your response.
Does && mean both conditions should met to execute the Advice?

Comment: correct. e1 and e2 should be met, whereas you probably mean the before the execution of e1 or the exectuion of e2 execute this advice. As I mentioned it is more or less an if statement and it will only execute the advice if it resolves to `true`.